# Changing SQL Server 2016 compatibility level to 2012

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2014, compatibility

On my current project we are using SQL server 2016 with the compatibility level 2012(110) and i want to change it to 2016. Here is my questions:

- Are we losing performance improvement with this compatibility level(2012) and how can i prove it?
- In the past, as my collages said they tried this and some of indexes didn't work. Is there any risk like that?
- Whats your opinion? Is it worth to try?

Best Regards

Comment: There are features from older versions of sql server that are deprecated but supported in sql server 2012 that are no longer supported in sql server 2016. Check out the documentation for each version of sql server would be a start. For example this one: https://learn.microsoft.com/sv-se/sql/database-engine/deprecated-database-engine-features-in-sql-server-2016?view=sql-server-2014

 What do you mean that some indexes are not working? They can't be created, they can't be rebuilt, or they perform poorly?

Comment: As they said execution plan didn't use same of indexes like they weren't exist.

Answer (score 1):

> Whats your opinion? Is it worth to try?

Yes it is,
but you should test it in your database.

`Compatibility level` means the possibility of new `features` usage + use of new `cardinality estimator`, the first is a good thing, the second depends.

> In the past, as my collages said they tried this and some of indexes
>   didn't work. Is there any risk like that?

This mieans that the new `cardinality estimator` has made different estimations and as a consequence the plan was different and did not use some indexes.
This can be good o bad, you should compare `execution time`, not "index usage".
If you see that some queries perform worse, you can use `query hint` to use the legacy cardinality estimator at `query level`:

```
OPTION(QUERYTRACEON 9481)
```

You can enable legacy cardinality estimator even on `server level`:

```
DBCC TRACEON(9481, –1)
```

with this enabled you'll have all the old plans but still can use new features of 2016.

Here you can read more about cardinality estimator and hints related to it:
[SQL Server 2016 Upgrade Testing with the New Cardinality Estimator: Context Matters](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/erin/sql-server-2016-upgrade-testing-with-the-new-cardinality-estimator-context-matters/)